# using Alpine js to show something for exactly one second

Tags: alpine.js

I'd like my alpine js to x-show something for only one second, repeatedly, every 60 seconds. I've got a js timer (likely more robust than I need) and I can get x-text to show me the seconds counting down and then resetting, but I can't quite figure out what to put into x-show to get the div to display at the time I've designated. Here's my html/alpine

```
  <p x-text="time().seconds"></p>

<div x-show="time().seconds.value === 48">
hello
</div>
```

and my javascript timer:

```
  function timer(expiry) {
  return {
    expiry: expiry,
    remaining:null,
    init() {
      this.setRemaining()
      setInterval(() => {
        this.setRemaining();
      }, 1000);
    },
    setRemaining() {
      const diff = this.expiry - new Date().getTime();
      this.remaining =  parseInt(diff / 1000);
    },
    days() {
      return {
        value:this.remaining / 86400,
        remaining:this.remaining % 86400
      };
    },
    hours() {
      return {
        value:this.days().remaining / 3600,
        remaining:this.days().remaining % 3600
      };
    },
    minutes() {
        return {
        value:this.hours().remaining / 60,
        remaining:this.hours().remaining % 60
      };
    },
    seconds() {
        return {
        value:this.minutes().remaining,
      };
    },
    format(value) {
      return ("0" + parseInt(value)).slice(-2)
    },
    time(){
        return {
        days:this.format(this.days().value),
        hours:this.format(this.hours().value),
        minutes:this.format(this.minutes().value),
        seconds:this.format(this.seconds().value),
      }
    },
  }
}

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format function to a string:

```
format(value) {
 return ("0" + value).slice(-2)
}
```

and then x-show worked fine with this modification:

```
<div x-show="time().seconds === '48'">
  hello
</div>
```